# React time lines

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a big problem with React TimeLines Package(https://openbase.com/js/react-timelines)

I want something like this photo:
( having 3 P tags with different ClassNames)
[image]

but in default case of this package I cant do it! [image]

I think I should use something like createElement and textContent in JS. but I dont know how!

My Codes:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Timeline from "react-timelines";

import "react-timelines/lib/css/style.css";

import { START_YEAR, NUM_OF_YEARS, NUM_OF_TRACKS } from "./constant";

import { buildTimebar, buildTrack } from "./builder";

import { fill } from "./utils";

const now = new Date("2021-01-01");

const timebar = buildTimebar();

// eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
const clickElement = (element) =>
  alert(`Clicked element\n${JSON.stringify(element, null, 2)}`);

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const tracksById = fill(NUM_OF_TRACKS).reduce((acc, i) => {
      const track = buildTrack(i + 1);
      acc[track.id] = track;
      return acc;
    }, {});

    this.state = {
      open: false,
      zoom: 2,
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-unused-state
      tracksById,
      tracks: Object.values(tracksById),
    };
  }

  handleToggleOpen = () => {
    this.setState(({ open }) => ({ open: !open }));
  };


  handleToggleTrackOpen = (track) => {
    this.setState((state) => {
      const tracksById = {
        ...state.tracksById,
        [track.id]: {
          ...track,
          isOpen: !track.isOpen,
        },
      };

      return {
        tracksById,
        tracks: Object.values(tracksById),
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { open, zoom, tracks } = this.state;
    const start = new Date(`${START_YEAR}`);
    const end = new Date(`${START_YEAR + NUM_OF_YEARS}`);
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Timeline
          scale={{
            start,
            end,
            zoom,
          }}
          isOpen={open}
          toggleOpen={this.handleToggleOpen}
          clickElement={clickElement}
          timebar={timebar}
          tracks={tracks}
          now={now}
          enableSticky
          scrollToNow
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

builder.js:

```
export const buildElement = ({ trackId, start, end, i }) => {
  const bgColor = nextColor();
  const color = colourIsLight(...hexToRgb(bgColor)) ? "#000000" : "#ffffff";
  return {
    id: `t-${trackId}-el-${i}`,
    title: "Bye Title: Hello Type: String",
    start,
    end,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: `#${bgColor}`,
      color,
      borderRadius: "12px",
      width: "auto",
      height: "120px",
      textTransform: "capitalize",
    },
  };
};
```